# Run function on specific rows of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that takes as one of its inputs a dataframe, which is indexed by date. How can I run the function only on a subset of the dataframe (say, from 2005-2010)? I don't think I can just drop the rest of the rows from the dataframe because part of the function keeps track of a rolling average, and thus the first few rows would depend on dates I am not considering.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset the dataframe with the rows that you need:

```
df.iloc[0:5] ## Gives only 5 rows
```

Then, you can run the function on these rows, like this:

```
df.iloc[0:5].apply(my_function)
```